# Initating ACRA causes additional issues with volley, possible fix?

Tags: java, android, android-volley, acra

I am using Volley for network calls! Also I am using the LRU cache to cache images and populate using volley's own `NetworkImageView`. So far things were working fine! However, the moment i called to initialie ACRA(Crash reporter) in my Application class, Volley is creating NullPointerException. And I am absolutely clueless where to look for the bug.
This is the code of my Application class.

**AppController.class**

```
    @ReportsCrashes()

public class AppController extends Application
{
    public static final String TAG = AppController.class.getSimpleName();

    private RequestQueue mRequestQueue;
    private ImageLoader mImageLoader;



    private static AppController mInstance;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        ACRA.init(this);

    }

    public static synchronized AppController getInstance() {
        return mInstance;
    }

    public RequestQueue getRequestQueue() {
        if (mRequestQueue == null) {
            mRequestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        }

        return mRequestQueue;
    }

    public ImageLoader getImageLoader() {
        getRequestQueue();
        if (mImageLoader == null) {
            mImageLoader = new ImageLoader(this.mRequestQueue,
                    new LruBitmapCache());
        }
        return this.mImageLoader;
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req, String tag) {
        // set the default tag if tag is empty
        req.setTag(TextUtils.isEmpty(tag) ? TAG : tag);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public <T> void addToRequestQueue(Request<T> req) {
        req.setTag(TAG);
        getRequestQueue().add(req);
    }

    public void cancelPendingRequests(Object tag) {
        if (mRequestQueue != null) {
            mRequestQueue.cancelAll(tag);
        }
    }
}
```

And the Exception is thrown in the Adapter of my `RecyclerView` wherein I am populating the cached items.

**CustomAdapter.class**

```
ImageLoader imageLoader = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
ImageLoader imageLoader2 = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
```

And the logcat output is :

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                      Process: com.mobloo.eduknow, PID: 28295
>                                                      java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader
>   com.mobloo.eduknow.AppController.getImageLoader()' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                          at com.mobloo.eduknow.CustomAdapter.(CustomAdapter.java:33)
>                                                          at com.mobloo.eduknow.FeedsFragment.onCreateView(FeedsFragment.java:57)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1962)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1067)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1248)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:738)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1613)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:570)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:141)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:1106)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:952)
>                                                          at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:1474)
>                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
>                                                          at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChildHorizontal(RelativeLayout.java:715)
>                                                          at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:461)
>                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                          at android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
>                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
>                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
>                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
>                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
>                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:748)
>                                                          at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:630)
>                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5951)
>                                                          at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:194)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2643)
>                                                          at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18794)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2100)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1216)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1452)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1107)
>                                                          at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6013)
>                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:858)
>                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:670)
>                                                          at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:606)
>                                                          at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:844)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
>                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
>                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)

So does the ACRA initialization affects Volley so that Volley is not properly initiated to throw a NullPointerException? What's a possible fix for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mInstance` is `null`, because you never assign a value to it. This has nothing to do with ACRA, other than perhaps you accidentally deleted some code when you added in ACRA.

Comment: Indeed, accidentally removed `mInstance = this;` from `onCreate()`